# Comma before "people, which do this and this"

Tags: punctuation, relative-clauses, restrictive-clauses

In this sentence, is the second comma correct?

> However, most operators are moving towards P2P networks, 
>       which do not have central servers.

From the hot tip on [this site](http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/which_that_who_with_commas.htm), I would think it is correct. I can remove the part starting with which and the sentence is perfectly useful to any reader who knows what a P2P network is.

EDIT: There are no P2P networks with central servers that I could refer to, so I think the comment answers the question.

Comment: Removing the comma would imply there are _P2P networks which **have** central servers_ and you're specifying those which do **not** have them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, most operators are moving towards P2P networks, which do not have central servers.

This would infer that all P2P networks do not have central servers (which is true).

> However, most operators are moving towards P2P networks which do not have central servers.

By removing the comma, this would relate to a subset of P2P networks that don't have central servers (which is technically false).